# I'm getting an error when I open my WordPress site

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is the error:

> Warning: require(/home/****/public_html/wp-includes/load.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/growfi5/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 21
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/****/public_html/wp-includes/load.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/*****/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 21

line 21 says

```
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/load.php' )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you may be missing one or more core WordPress files.

The load.php file should go in the `wp-includes` directory and you can see the source of the current version of that file at https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/load.php

After fixing this error you may run into other missing files.

It may be necessary to download the [latest](http://wordpress.org/latest.zip) version of WordPress and extract all the files to your WordPress installation to make sure you have all of the latest files.

Note: unpacking these files is typically safe and just makes sure you have the latest and correct version of all the WP files.

Answer (score 0):

drew010's answer is correct, but I'd like to offer a troubleshooting tip.

Did this problem come seemingly out of nowhere after you were doing something with the files on your website with, say, an FTP client like Filezilla?

If so, take a look at your root directory, and make sure everything is where is supposed to be, and that you didn't click and drag something out of its place accidentally.

I was stumped by the out-of-the-blue appearance of this bug until I realized I had accidentally put my wp-includes folder inside my wp-content folder.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked and solved about 5 years ago but this solution might help somebody else...

I had the same issue on a Wordpress installed via SSH Terminal.  My problem in this case was the folders owner and permissions.  Make sure you install using the right user group.  In my case I had to change from the root user and root group to the current account user and group by typing:

`chown -R youraccountuser:youraccountgroup ./`

Then also make sure all your folders and files have the right permissions set.  For me it was:

```
find /path/to/your/wordpress/install/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find /path/to/your/wordpress/install/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```